# Was the collapse and expand functionality removed from EditButton()?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm going through some SwiftFul Thinking tutorials and I noticed in Nick's code when he adds EditButton() he gets the functionality of the Edit button and a chevron to the right of each List title that allows the list to be collapsed or expanded.

[image: Nick's Code]

Now a few bits of code in Nick's tutorial have been deprecated, so I had to change the code to make my List work, but I can't seem to get that expand/collapse chevron to surface.

My Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListBootcamp: View {
    @State var fruits: [String] = [
        "apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"
    ]

    @State var veggies: [String] = [
        "tomato", "potato", "carrot"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header:
                    HStack {
                        Text("Fruits")
                        Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                    }
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.orange)
                ) {
                    ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                        Text(fruit.capitalized)
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                    .onMove(perform: move)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.pink)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Veggies").foregroundStyle(Color.blue)) {
                    ForEach(veggies, id: \.self) { veggies in
                        Text(veggies.capitalized)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Grocery List")
// Code in question here
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    EditButton()
                }

                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    addButton
                }
            }
        }
        .tint(.green)
    }

    var addButton: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            add()
        }
    }

    func delete(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        fruits.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }

    func move(indices: IndexSet, newOffset: Int) {
        fruits.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
    }

    func add() {
        fruits.append("coconut")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to iOS 17, `Section`s in lists would gain the ability to collapse depending on the `listStyle` and a few other factors that weren’t particularly opaque.

Now, if you want a `Section` to be able to expand and collapse, you should pass a Boolean binding to the Section’s initializer, e.g.:

```
@State private isExpanded = true

var body: some View {
  List {
    Section(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
      // your list rows go here
    } header: {
      HStack {
        Text(“Fruits”)
        Image(systemName: “flame.fill”)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are several `Section` initializers that accept an `isExpanded` argument - for example [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/init(isexpanded:content:header:)-9bdul). In the documentation’s left hand pane you’ll see others.